# Message Object - Best Practice? |  Consider data attribute for pulling text in

Tags: javascript

Is this best practice way to send messages to the user?

Update:  This has been changed to a simple function call.

```
/**
 *Message - Sends message to the .innerHTML of an element
 */

var Message = ( function () 
{
    var messages = 
    {
        name:         'Please enter a valid name',
        email:        'Please enter a valid email',
        email_s:      'Please enter a valid email.',
        pass:         'Please enter password, 6-40 characters',
        url:          'Please enter a valid url',
        title:        'Please enter a valid title',
        tweet:        'Please enter a valid tweet',
        empty:        'Please complete all fields',
        same:         'Please make emails equal',
        taken:        'Sorry, that email is taken',
        validate:     'Please contact <a class="d" href="mailto:foo@foo.com">support</a> to reset your password',
    };
    var MessageInternal = function (element) 
    {
        this.element = element;
    };
    MessageInternal.prototype.display = function( type ) 
    {
        this.element.innerHTML = messages[ type ];
    };
    return MessageInternal;
} () );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are asking here, but I'll give some general pointers:

- I find that you have two different variables called `Message` very confusing.
- It's not really a good idea to add proprietary properties to DOM elements. You should consider using the HTML5 `dataset` API instead.
- It seems wrong to hard code the fade effect.
- IMHO this seems like a lot of code and unnecessarily over-engineered for displaying a simple message. It reminds me a lot how of the [Twitter bootstrap library](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#alerts) does things.

Comment: - decided to go with a simple function instead of module pattern.

Comment: - how is HTML 5 related here?...are you referring to the HTML5 data- attribute?

Comment: this is what you mean by dataset API methinks